# Does DisableTaskOffload disable all related LAN Adapter settings?

Tags: checksum, tcp-offload-engine

I have been getting problems disabling Checksum Offload in a lot of LAN adapters manually. Does setting the DisableTaskOffload value in the registry disable all of the related parameters regardless of LAN card? ie [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]

ie is the use of the LAN adapter offload capabilities controlled by Windows itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should disable all offload settings of all nics.
You need a reboot after create/modify the value

Comment: I have tested it on my PC and it works. I am hoping it will be the same for all other PCs